# Single login across multiple domain asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to implement functionality such that i have 2 websites . i would like to login user from one website and allow user to perform operations on other website.

Comment: If you want to register once and use the credentials in other applications then it is as mentioned in the above SO question. But if you want to login in one application and want to remain logged in another, you can do this by creating a secret token which you pass from one website to the other by URL or Authentication Headers which will validate your user internally and user will not need to login again.

Comment: How i can create security token